# How to make sure that email is not sent twice with task queue usage?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, cron, task-queue

I would like to change my GAE app logic and to start emails sending with task queue usage.

Currently I have a cron job, which runs each 15 minutes and read messages to be sent from the datastore:

```
class SendMessagesHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        emails_quota_exceeded = models.get_system_value('emails_quota_exceeded')
        if emails_quota_exceeded == 0 or emails_quota_exceeded == None:
            messages = models.get_emails_queue()
            for message in messages:
                try:
                    ...
                    email.send()
                    models.update_email_status(message.key.id()) # update email status indicating that the mail has been sent 
                except apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError, error_message:
                    models.set_system_value(what='emails_quota_exceeded', val=1)
                    logging.warning('E-mails quota exceeded for today: %s' % error_message)
                    break
        else:
            logging.info('Free quota to send e-mails is exceeded')
```

If I use task queues, then I'll get something like:

```
for message in messages:
    taskqueue.add(url='/sendmsg', payload=message)
```

In this scenario it is possible that the same message will be sent twice (or even more times) - for ex., if it wasn't sent yet, but cron job was executed second time.
If I update email status immediately after adding the message to the queue:

```
for message in messages:
    taskqueue.add(url='/sendmsg', payload=message)
    models.update_email_status(message.key.id()) # update email status indicating that the mail has been sent
```

then it is possible that the message will never be sent. For ex., if exception happened during e-mail sending. Understand that the task will be retried, but in case quota is exceeded for today, then retries will not help.

I think I can also re-read the status of each message at task queue before trying to sent it, but it will cost me additional read operations.

What's the best way to handle it?

Comment: A read is not very expensive. You can send a bcc to yourself to make sure it has been send.

Comment: @voscausa, to be copied in 100 messages per day? No, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving your task a name including the `key.id()` will prevent it from being sent twice:

```
task_name = ''.join(['myemail-', str(mykey)])
try:
    taskqueue.Task(
        url="/someURL/send-single-email",
        name=task_name,
        method="POST",
        params={
           "subject": subject,  
           "body": body,
           "to": to,
           "from": from }
    ).add(queue_name="mail-queue")
except:
    pass #throws TombstonedTaskError(InvalidTaskError) if tombstoned name used.
```

There may be times when you want to send follow-up emails for messages with the same key.  Therefore, I would recommend adding a `date` or `datetime` stamp to the task name.  This will allow you to send other messages of the same key at a later time:

```
 task_name = ''.join(['myemail-', str(mykey), str(datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=8))]).translate(string.maketrans('.:_ ', '----'))
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. But where have you found the information that task name must be unique and that `TombstonedTaskError` is raised when it is not?

Comment: I do not see the docs off hand, but the task name was implemented for exactly this purpose, so tasks are not executed repeatedly.  Also, I should add that, if you want to send emails for messages of the same key more than once, you can also add a `date` or `datetime` to the task_name.  That would allow you to send emails for messages of the same key later.  `''.join(['myemail-', str(mykey), str(datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=8))]).translate(string.maketrans('.:_ ', '----'))`

Comment: Aah, I found the description there - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#Python_Task_names.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the recommendation for the `datetime` stamp in the task name.

Comment: Hmm, sometimes I get TaskAlreadyExistsError instead of TombstonedTaskError... looks like I should catch both exceptions.